# Yum update - Could not resolve host

Tags: centos, yum

I am using a system with an i5 processor and CentOS 7 os. In order to setup a remote session with OEM for troubleshooting session, I wanted to install the TeamViewer application on my system.

I followed the instructions as per TeamViewer website and ran a command

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
```

But unfortunately, the command gives error as below

> could not resolve the host,archieve

On further referring to online forums, I ran the code

```
sudo yum update
```

The above command is also showcasing error
'could not resolve the host,archieve'

Later, I checked the internet connection, connected to my mobile usb tethering. The Firefox browser was fetching website details properly.

I probed ping command and typed

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

The above command outputs

> destination host not reachable

I even disabled firewallD.

What might be the issue with ping 8.8.8.8 not working despite a proper internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the file /etc/resolv.conf and see if the nameserver entries are added. Try adding the below entries in file /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks ping 8.8.8.8 is responding, but outer problem i.e. yum update is still exhibiting 'could not resolve host: archieve' error. Can you sort this out? I was under the impression pinging 8.8.8.8 will solve this.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the base URL in any of the repo file is not responding. Can you please provide a full screenshot of the error?

Comment: yes you are right. When I check the base url in repo file it was referring to www.archiver.com/CentOS/7.3.1611. I visited the website but it was displaying unrelated stuff. How to overcome this and change it to updated CentOS-Base.repo?

Comment: Issue is sorted out by commenting the archiver link and uncommenting mirrorlist list. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Glad I could help :)